# ng-table replacement in angular 11

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, ngtable

I'm trying to convert my old code from angularjs to angular11/ javascript to typescript. I'm look for the best way to replace `ng-table` in angular 11 because when I typed in ng-table, the IDE highlight and let me know that attribute ng-table is not allowed here. What should I do in this case? Thanks

```
    <table id="tb1" ng-table="items" class="table table-hover" >
       <button  name="toggle{{ (items.page() - 1) * items.count() + $index }}" class="btn btn-link btn-mini" 
            ng-click="function()">
              <span [hidden]="!show">  Undo Delete </span>
              <span [hidden]="show">"   Delete </span>
            </button>
</table
```

Comment: Are you sure about angular 11? ng-table, ng-click this is part of angularJS, it is a two different tools

Comment: @YanKoshelev Hi, yes i'm trying to convert my code from angularjs to angular11/javascript to typescript. That's why i'm trying to find equivalent thing with for ng-table. let me edit my question.thanks

Comment: Take a look at @swimlane/ngx-datatable or ag-grid-community. Both popular packages that have similar features but for newer Angular versions. They will probably require a reasonable amount of refactoring, but there are tons of demos in the documentation for you to look at. Angular-Material's table elements are also very handy but that may introduce a larger change to your application than the others.